# how to update post content field in wordpress

Tags: metabox

i have used add meta boxes to customize page content and use wp_update_post to save it.

when im creating new page in wordpress it inserts two new record in wp_posts table.
one of them has published status and the other one has review status, but the issue is Their post_content field have different values.

the post_content field of the one with publish status has classic editor value and the other one has my custom content that i added as meta boxes.

how can i isert same post_content for both of them?

[image]

Comment: You'll probably need to share the code you're using in order for others to understand it well enough to suggest how to fix the problem. :)

Comment: it's likely one s a revision or draft but it's only speculation, we must see the code to be able to understand what's going on, metaboxes modifying the post_content that gets saved in the database is extraordinarily rare and highly unusual, so I'm assuming you mean you're using a shortcode? What was the problem that you're trying to solve that lead you to this?